# Raku Regex to capture and modify the LFM code blocks

Tags: regex, markdown, raku, github-flavored-markdown

*Update*: Corrected code added below

I have a *Leanpub flavored markdown** file named `sample.md` I'd like  to convert its code blocks into *Github flavored markdown* style using `Raku Regex`

```
Here's a sample **ruby** code, which
prints the elements of an array:

{:lang="ruby"}
    ['Ian','Rich','Jon'].each {|x| puts x}

Here's a sample **shell** code, which
removes the ending commas and
finds all folders in the current path:

{:lang="shell"}
    sed s/,$//g
    find . -type d
```

In order to capture the `lang` value, e.g. `ruby`  from the `{:lang="ruby"}` and convert it into

````
```ruby
````

I use this code

````
my @in="sample.md".IO.lines;
my @out;
for @in.kv -> $key,$val {
    if $val.starts-with("\{:lang") {
       if $val ~~ /^{:lang="([a-z]+)"}$/ { # capture lang
           @out[$key]="```$0"; # convert it into ```ruby
           $key++;
           while @in[$key].starts-with("    ") {
                 @out[$key]=@in[$key].trim-leading;
                 $key++;
           }
           @out[$key]="```";
       }
    }
    @out[$key]=$val;
}
````

The line containing the Regex gives
**Cannot modify an immutable Pair (lang => True)** error.

I've just started out using Regexes. Instead of `([a-z]+)` I've tried `(\w)` and it gave the `Unrecognized backslash sequence: '\w'` error, among other things.

How to correctly capture and modify the `lang` value using Regex?

- the LFM format just estimated

## Corrected code:

````
my @in="sample.md".IO.lines;
my \len=@in.elems;
my @out;
my $k = 0;

while ($k < len) {
    if @in[$k] ~~ / ^ '{:lang="' (\w+) '"}' $ / { 
    push @out, "```$0";
    $k++;
    while @in[$k].starts-with("    ") {
        push @out, @in[$k].trim-leading;
        $k++;   }
    push @out, "```";
    }
    push @out, @in[$k];
    $k++;
}

for @out {print "$_\n"}
````

Comment: You'll probably want to use `<->` instead of just `->` in your for loop

Comment: Tried it now (did the operator `<->`) and it gave *Parameter '$key' expects a writable container (variable) as an
argument, but got '0' (Int) as a value without a container.* error.

Comment: Dear @user0721090601 ... please can you state why <-> beats -> and maybe reference the relevant doc page (I can't find it)

Comment: @p6steve It's [doc'd here](https://docs.raku.org/type/Block#index-entry-%3C-%3E). (I found it by typing `<->` into the doc search box; perhaps it was added to the search index in response to your comment?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- **TL?** Then read @jjemerelo's excellent answer which not only provides a *one-line* solution but much more in a compact form **;**
- **DR?** Aw, imo you're missing some good stuff in this answer that JJ (reasonably!) ignores. Though, again, JJ's is the bomb. Go read it first. :)

## Using a Perl regex

There are many dialects of regex. The regex pattern you've used is a Perl regex but you haven't told Raku that. So it's interpreting your regex as a Raku regex, not a Perl regex. It's like feeding Python code to `perl`. So the error message is useless.

---

One option is to switch to Perl regex handling. To do that, this code:

```
      /^{:lang="([a-z]+)"}$/
```

needs `m :P5` at the start:

```
m :P5 /^{:lang="([a-z]+)"}$/
```

The `m` is implicit when you use `/.../` in a context where it is presumed you mean to immediately match, but because the `:P5` "adverb" is being added to modify how Raku interprets the pattern in the regex, one has to also add the `m`.

`:P5` only supports a limited set of Perl's regex patterns. That said, it should be enough for the regex you've written in your question.

## Using a Raku regex

If you want to use a Raku regex you have to learn the Raku regex language.

The "spirit" of the Raku regex language is the same as Perl's, and some of the absolute basic syntax is the same as Perl's, but it's different enough that you should view it as yet another dialect of regex, just one that's generally "powered up" relative to Perl's regexes.

To rewrite the regex in Raku format I think it would be:

```
/ ^ '{:lang="' (<[a..z]>+) '"}' $ /
```

(Taking advantage of the fact whitespace in Raku regexes is ignored.)

## Other problems in your code

After fixing the regex, one encounters other problems in your code.

The first problem I encountered is that `$key` is read-only, so `$key++` fails. One option is to make it writable, by writing `-> $key is copy ...`, which makes `$key` a read-write copy of the index passed by the `.kv`.

But fixing that leads to another problem. And the code is so complex I've concluded I'd best not chase things further. I've addressed your immediate obstacle and hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know there was a distinction between Perl 5 and Raku Regex. I've started learning Raku Regex actually just since yesterday afternoon and I haven't used the Raku for a while so I've forgotten the bits.

Comment: Yes the `$key` 's being read-only gives an error but I couldn't debug it because of the Regex error. Making it  `$key is copy, $val` fixed the problem. Btw, making the capture `(\w+)` works better. Actually I had initially made it `(\w+)` but probably because of the Perl 5 Regex thing, it gave an error; now it works fine. Now there's only one thing left. It's adding the enclosing `\`\`\``  to the end of the code blocks.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Makes sense. :) I don't know when you accepted my answer, but if you did so before you saw JJs, and/or want later readers to see it first (I do!), please know that on SO it's OK to change your mind (even multiple times) about which answer to accept if you later decide a different answer, with the latest edits, is now the best one to accept. I think my answer is fine, but always think about future readers, and would love their attention to first be drawn to JJs beautifully short, sweet and, imo, better answer to "How to correctly capture and modify the lang value using Regex?".

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen "Btw, making the capture `(\w+)` works better." I only just now realized I had a mistake in my Raku regex. I had written `([a..z]+)` which will match one or more sequences of the pattern `a..z`, i.e. a four letter substring that starts with an `a` and ends with a `z`. Which isn't remotely what I intended! I've now edited my answer for the Raku equivalent to a Perl regex's `[a-z]` as it should be: `<[a..z]>`. See [the doc](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Enumerated_character_classes_and_ranges) for further discussion of character ranges in Raku regexes.

Answer (score 9):

This one-liner seems to solve the problem:

````
say S:g /\{\: "lang" \= \" (\w+) \" \} /```$0/ given "text.md".IO.slurp;
````

Let's try and explain what was going on, however. The error was a regular expression grammar error, caused by having a `:` being followed by a name, and all that inside a curly. `{}` runs code inside a regex. Raiph's answer is (obviously) correct, by changing it to a Perl regular expression. But what I've done here is to change it to a Raku's [non-destructive substitution](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#S///_non-destructive_substitution), with the `:g` global flag, to make it act on the whole file (slurped at the end of the line; I've saved it to a file called `text.md`). So what this does is to slurp your target file, with `given` it's saved in the `$_` topic variable, and printed once the substitution has been made. Good thing is if you want to make more substitutions you can shove another such expression to the front, and it will act on the output.
Using this kind of expression is always going to be conceptually simpler, and possibly faster, than dealing with a text line by line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a helpful answer because I've just tried it and it works. I've started learning the Regex part of Raku since yesterday afternoon. The explanation on how that one-liner works is good.